# Reading file into 2d Array Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Im reading from a file that looks like this

5

0 3 1 4 2

4 0 6 1 4

1 2 0 6 5

6 3 1 0 8

4 1 9 3 0

the first number is irrelevant. I want to start reading from line 2. I am able to read line 1 and store it but I am having trouble reading the rest of the array.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class TSM {
private static int numOfCities;
private static int[][] arr;

public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException{
    numOfCities = 0;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new     FileReader("/Users/sly/Desktop/tsp.txt"));   
    String line = " ";
    String [] temp;

    while ((line = br.readLine())!= null){ 

        if(line.trim().length() ==1) { //set value of first line in file to be numOfCities
            numOfCities = Integer.parseInt(line);
            System.out.println("There are"+ " " + numOfCities+ " " + "Number of cities");

        } else{ 
            temp = line.split(" "); //split spaces

            for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j<arr.length; j++) {    
                    arr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    printArray();
}

public static void printArray () { 
         for (int i =0; i <arr.length; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
          }
          System.out.println("");
         }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Where does your code get hung up?

Comment: What problem are you facing?? `Trouble` doesn't explain your problem clearly.

Comment: Just a side note here, you only need to do `System.out.println()` not `System.out.println("")`, they have the same effect. Also, never append two string constants ("There are" + " " and " " + "Number of cites"), as it does take a little bit of time to append, and it's simpler just to directly hand it "There are " or " Number of cities"

Answer (score 4):

`arr` has not been correctly initialised:

```
private static int[][] arr;
```

Change to:

```
private static int[][] arr = new int[5][5]; // for example. Dimensions
                                            // guessed from file content.
```

Comment: Actually, rather say new int[numOfCities][numOfCities] in the code section which parses the first number (yes, in this case 5), but right idea, so +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

Logically, you have some problem in your else part. Each line represents a row in your two dimensionl array. It should be somewhat as follows -

```
else { 
    temp = line.split(" "); //split spaces 
    int[] newRow = new int[temp.length];
    //for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){ 
    for (int j = 0; j<temp.length; j++){ 
        newRow[j] = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]); 
    } 
    //} 
    //declare currentRowIndex outside while loop with initial value of 0
    arr[currentRowIndex] = newRow; 
    //increment currentRowIndex on each iteraton of the while loop
}
```

Comment: Was going to mention this, but figured I'd leave him to figure that out when he got to it, feel like I posted enough stuff to fix as comments, but +1 anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You can take out this part of the code in the loop:

```
if(line.trim().length() ==1) { //set value of first line in file to be numOfCities
    numOfCities = Integer.parseInt(line);
    System.out.println("There are"+ " " + numOfCities+ " " + "Number of cities");
} else {
```

because what you can do is above the while loop put this:

```
numOfCities = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
System.out.println("There are"+ " " + numOfCities+ " " + "Number of cities");
```

and what that will do is read the first line, set it to the number of cities, then go into the while loop and start at the SECOND line instead of the first. So your whole code will be:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class TSM {
    private static int numOfCities;
    private static int[][] arr = new int[5][5];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException{
        numOfCities = 0;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/sly/Desktop/tsp.txt"));   
        String line = " ";
        String [] temp;

        numOfCities = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); //Reads first line then starts at while loop in second
        System.out.println("There are"+ " " + numOfCities+ " " + "Number of cities");

        while ((line = br.readLine())!= null){ 
            temp = line.split(" "); //split spaces

            for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j<arr.length; j++) {    
                    arr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
                }
            }

        }
        printArray();
    }

    public static void printArray () { 
        for (int i =0; i <arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }    
}
```

Hope it helps!